# Convert SVG co-ordinate to page co-ordinate in D3 js

Tags: animation, d3.js, svg, tooltip

I am trying to show an animated tool-tip, changing its position after every 1 second, for multiple graphs.

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
        .attr("id", "tooltip")
        .attr("class", "tooltip");
```

As this is a div, translate will not work with this. So, I am trying to translate like this way, with svg co-ordinates.

```
tooltip.html("Tooltip")
            .style("left", x(currentTime) + "px")
            .style("top", height + "px");
```

But it takes this as page co-ordinate value.

How to convert SVG co-ordinate to page co-ordinate?
Or is there any other way to create tool-tip as a SVG element?

Comment: You might consider writing the div using the enter, update, exit pattern - assuming data comes in every second.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `div` tooltip is absolutely position, your "page" coordinate is just the position of the `svg` element plus the position of the thing in the svg element.

Here's a quick example (mouse over the circles):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="d3@4.0.0" data-semver="4.0.0" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <svg 
      width="300" height="300" 
      style="left: 100px; top: 100px; position: absolute">
    </svg>
    <div id="tooltip" style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black">
      This is my tooltip
    </div>
    <script>
      var json = [
        {x: Math.random() * 300, y: Math.random() * 300},
        {x: Math.random() * 300, y: Math.random() * 300},
        {x: Math.random() * 300, y: Math.random() * 300}
      ];
      
      var svg = d3.select('svg');
      
      svg
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(json)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d){ return d.x })
        .attr('cy', function(d){ return d.y })
        .attr('r', 30)
        .style('fill', 'red')
        .on('mouseover', function(d){
          var svgPos = svg.node().getBoundingClientRect();
          d3.select('#tooltip')
            .style('left', svgPos.left + d.x + 'px')
            .style('top', svgPos.top + d.y + 'px');
        })
      
    </script>
    
  </body>

</html>
```